# ASP.Net Web API 2 returning 404 on POST (sometimes)

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I've recently run into an issue with a simple Web API service I'm running for a customer. The service accepts either a GET or a POST. The POST method is defined like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult PostUpload(UploadModel model)
{ ... }
```

The model looks like this:

```
public class UploadModel
{
    public Guid UserKey { get; set; }
    public string OrgCode { get; set; }
    public byte[] Export { get; set; }
}
```

The customer reported today that he's started having trouble with the client program we built to interact with the service. The program logs whenever it receives a status code from the service other that 200. Whenever the customer runs the program, he's receives a 404 - Not Found. I verified in the IIS logs that the program is sending a POST request, and that the URI is correct.

When I run the program, it always receives a 200 status.

The code in the method only returns one of two possible IHttpActionResult: Ok if there were no issues, otherwise InternalServerError().

Using Postman, I've tried sending a variety of different combinations/values for parameters UserKey, OrgCode, and Export, but I can't get the API to send back anything other than 200 or 500 status. I've tried using the same data as the customer, and from my end it always goes through.

It seems to be some sort of routing issue, like it can't identify the correct method, but I can't see what the issue is. Would appreciate someone pointing out what I'm obviously missing.

Comment: How have you configured your routing? Are you using convention based routing or attribute routing?

Comment: Convention-based. A POST to /api/DataExports/Upload returns a 200 for me, a 404 for the customer using the same application and sending the same data. Next step I guess is capturing the request info as it hits the site to see if there's a proxy or something on his end screwing with the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing the resolution with the community: After further contact with the customer, it turns out that the data I had to test with wasn't the same as what he had. The data he was sending in the POST was quite a lot larger than what I was sending. This triggered a thought regarding something I had run into in the past. I was so focused on the URI and routing, and the specific error (404) that I didn't think about max allowed upload size.

Setting the following in the web config to allow requests of up to 100MB fixed the issue:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="102400" />
</system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webServer>
```